# How can I graph a 3D timeseries of a dataset that contains multiple lines at different y-axis scales?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a 3D graph of a dataset that contains one x-axis (time_step), and about 8 y-axes at different scales. The reason I need to do so, is to show a significant change in the series that can be observed in all the different features at a particular point in time.

The issue I am running into is the fact that they y-axes are in different scales. For example, bonding_energy is around 1000, whereas potential is around-58000. What I would like to do is scale the y-axes around to place the lines somewhat parallel to one another.

Here is a sample of the dataset I am working with:[image]

Here is an example of the image I am trying to create: [image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.

Comment: Try plotting with a log scale. Or normalize the data first.

Comment: Some nice [normalization/standardization answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10289) on stats.stackexchange

Comment: I agree with wwii, if you have 8 different scales for your data the easiest/best way to go is normalize each series